# how to do sorting of distance in 2d array using fortran code?

Tags: sorting, fortran

I want to sort the distance. for example r(1,3)< r(1,2) then r(1,3) should come first .
input file of `dist.txt` like this

```
1,2,3.5
1,3,0.5
1,4,4.7
1,5,4,5
```

output file of `sort.txt`should be like this

```
1, 3, 0.5
1,2, 3.5
1,5, 4.5
1,4,4.7
```

here first column is `i` and second column `j` then third column is `r(i,j)`.
So here I have wrote down one code in fortran which can do sorting for 2D array. But that code has problem If some can fix. I will be so glad.

```
 program sort
  implicit none
  character CN*8,O*7
  integer i,m,k,j
  integer n,nmax,ind,num
  integer L
  parameter (n=3,m=n**2-n)
  double precision xbox,rq
  parameter (nmax=3091,nconf=1)
  double precision atom(nmax),id(nmax),ox(nmax),oy(nmax),oz(nmax)
  double precision xij,yij,zij,rij,t
  double precision a(n,n)
  double precision r(n,n)
  open(unit=10,status='unknown',file='a.gro')

   do i=1,n
     read(10,'(A8,A7,1i5,3f8.3)')CN,O,num,ox(i),oy(i),oz(i)
   enddo
     read(10,*)xbox        ! read the xbox for PBC

   t=0.0d0
  open(unit=3,file='dist.txt')
  open(unit=4,file='2d_1d_dist.txt')
  open(unit=5,file='sort.txt')
   do i=1,n
    do j=1,n
   if(i .ne. j) then
   xij=ox(i)-ox(j)
   yij=oy(i)-oy(j)
   zij=oz(i)-oz(j)
   xij=xij - nint(xij/xbox)*xbox
   yij=yij - nint(yij/xbox)*xbox
   zij=zij - nint(zij/xbox)*xbox
   r(i,j)=dsqrt(xij**2 + yij**2 + zij**2) !distance calculation
    write(3,'(i3,2x,i3,4x,f17.15)') i,j, r(i,j)
    endif
    enddo
    enddo


  t=0.0d0
  do i = 1,m-2
  do j = i+1,m-1
  if(i .ne. j) then
  write(4,*) r(i,j),"   ", r(i,j+1)
  if (r(i,j) .gt. r(i,j+1)) then
   t=r(i,j)
  r(i,j)=r(i,j+1)
  r(i,j+1)=t
  endif
   endif
  write(5,*) r(i,j)
  enddo
  enddo
  END program sort
```

Please look at the code.

Comment: It does not look like you need to sort a 2-D array. From your sample input output files, it looks like pair distances have already been computed and you only need to sort on the 3rd column. Either use an index array or sort all 3 columns bases on 3rd column.

Comment: What kind of problem does it have? An error  message? Which one? Incorrect results? How incorrect? What is the output of the current program? See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I think of when I encounter such a situation is: Do I need to write my own program?

Quick answer here is no: Linux/Unix has the `sort` command that works just fine:

```
sort -t, -k3 -g dist.txt
```

- `-t,` tells sort that the field separator is the comma,
- `-k3` tells it to sort according to the 3rd field,
- `-g` tells it to use a general numeric sort

If I needed to do that using Fortran, I would probably read `i`, `j`, and `r` into separate 1-D arrays, then write a sorting routine that not only sorts `r`, but also returns the order. Then you can easily rearrange the `i` and `j` arrays to correspond to the same order. See this example:

```
program sort_r

    implicit none
    integer :: u
    integer, parameter :: num_of_elements = 4
    integer :: i(num_of_elements), j(num_of_elements)
    real :: r(num_of_elements)
    integer :: order(num_of_elements)
    integer :: ii
    open(newunit=u, file='dist.txt')
    do ii=1, num_of_elements
        read(u, *) i(ii), j(ii), r(ii)
    end do
    close(u)
    order = [(ii, ii=1, num_of_elements)]
    call qsort(r, first=1, last=num_of_elements, order=order)
    i(:) = i(order)
    j(:) = j(order)
    do ii = 1, num_of_elements
        write(*,'(I0,",",I0,",",F3.1)') i(ii), j(ii), r(ii)
    end do

contains
    recursive subroutine qsort(a, first, last, order)
        real, intent(inout) :: a(:)
        integer, intent(in) :: first, last
        integer, intent(inout) :: order(:)
        ! Prerequsits:
        !       first >= lbound(a, 1)
        !       last <= lbound(a, 1)
        !       lbound(a, 1) == lbound(order, 1)
        !       ubound(a, 1) == ubound(order, 1)
        real :: pivot
        integer :: i, j

        if (.not. first < last) return ! less than 2 elements

        ! Get pivot from middle to beginning of subarray.
        call swap(a, first, (first+last)/2, order)
        pivot = a(first)
        i = first + 1
        j = last

        do while (j >= i)
            ! move up from left while elements are smaller than pivot
            do while (a(i) < pivot)
                i = i + 1
            end do
            ! move down from right while elements are larger than pivot
            do while (a(j) > pivot)
                j = j - 1
            end do
            ! If we moved past the other index, exit loop
            if (j < i) exit

            ! We have found a larger than pivot element left of a smaller than
            ! pivot element to the right, swap the two, move the indices to next
            call swap(a,i,j,order)
            i = i + 1
            j = j - 1
        end do

        ! Move pivot back to centre
        call swap(a,first,j, order)

        call qsort(a,first=first,last=j-1,order=order)
        call qsort(a,first=i,last=last,order=order)

    end subroutine qsort

    subroutine swap(a, i, j, order)
        real, intent(inout) :: a(:)
        integer, intent(in) :: i, j
        integer, intent(inout) :: order(:)
        real :: t
        integer :: k
        t = a(i)
        a(i) = a(j)
        a(j) = t
        k = order(i)
        order(i) = order(j)
        order(j) = k
    end subroutine swap

end program sort_r
```

Comment: @claudiasmith I have already commented that below your question. Please do not ignore it. Do *not* say "it isn't working", do *not* say "there is a problem". Say what is happening, error messages, results, other program output, all the details you might have. Please *do* read [ask], it is really important.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the answer example. Why is a(.) being swapped ? I would expect that the answer to the question is to treat a(n,n) as a vector a(n*n) and do an indexed sort in index order. It would be a straight forward conversion of order(k) > a(I,j)

Comment: The Quicksort algorithm, like many sorting algorithms, depends on swapping elements of an array. My `swap(A, i, j)` does exactly that: It swaps the `i`th and `j`th element of A. Because I need the final `order`, I also need to swap the corresponding elements of that array.

Comment: @chw21, the purpose of an indexed sort is to not alter the original array, but provide a "pointer" to the order. You should not "need to swap the corresponding elements of that array". Have you used your approach ?

Comment: I have 'used' my approach in the sense that I tested it, giving it her original input and it produced her expected output. With the limited information in the question I wasn't sure what she really wanted. But feel free to write your own answer, maybe that will illuminate things.